# Mixing cell types in a DataGridViewColumn

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Is it possible to have both DataGridViewComboBoxCells and DataGridViewTextBoxCells in a single DataGridViewColumn? Or am I absolutely restricted to having one type per column?

Comment: it's one type per column for all I know. You'd probably have to inherit from DataGridView to enable mixing different types up.

Comment: There are some workarounds - have a look at http://www.sommergyll.com/datagridview-usercontrols/datagridview-with-combobox.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a weird solution for this.
By default create the column as TextBox.
Handle the cell click or cell enter event.
In the event if the ColumnIndex matches, Convert the column type to ComboBox and set the items. 
Once the cell leave event fires from the respective column index, convert it back to textbox.
Dont forget to read the text from Combo before converting and set it to TextBox.

I know this is not apt solution but works.

I am eager to know if anyone has a better idea.

**Questioner's EDIT:**

Here was the code I ultimately wrote:

```
// Using CellClick and CellLeave in this way allows us
// to stick combo boxes in a particular row, even if the
// parent column type is different
private void dataGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= FIRST_COL && e.ColumnIndex <= LAST_COL && e.RowIndex == ROW_OF_INTEREST)
    {
        object value = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        dataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].CellTemplate = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        var cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell {Value = value};
        cell.Items.AddRange(_values);
        dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = cell;
    }
}

private void dataGrid_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= FIRST_COL && e.ColumnIndex <= LAST_COL && e.RowIndex == ROW_OF_INTEREST)
    {
        object value = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        dataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        var cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell {Value = value};
        dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = cell;
    }
}
```

Also, when creating the column, I had to make sure it was a generic column; i.e. not a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn:

```
var col = new DataGridViewColumn
              {
                  CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
              };
```

That way, I could change the CellTemplate later.

Comment: Thanks very much - this works quite nicely. I'd be interested in seeing if there are any "cleaner" solutions before marking as accepted; but this has been a great help!

Answer (score -1):

My code from the solution suggested in this post threw below error when I swapped cell.
`dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = cell;`

Unhandled exception of type "System.InvalidOperationException" in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Try to avoid the above cell swap in CellEnter and CellLeave events.
Instead, I use DataGridView.SelectionChanged event to handle both cell exit and cell enter.

```
       if (lastDGVCellInEdit != null)
       {
           //lastDGVCellInEdit is a global DataGridViewCell to store the last edit cell
           object value = lastDGVCellInEdit.Value;
           DGV.Columns[lastDGVCellInEdit.ColumnIndex].CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
           var newCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = value };
           DGV.Rows[lastDGVCellInEdit.RowIndex].Cells[lastDGVCellInEdit.ColumnIndex] = newCell;
           lastDGVCellInEdit = null;
       }

       if (DGV.SelectedCells.Count == 1)
       {
           DataGridViewCell sCell = DGV.SelectedCells[0];
           int rowIndex = sCell.RowIndex;
           int columnIndex = sCell.ColumnIndex;
           //ComboItems are stored in Tag of DataGridViewRow
           if (DGV.Rows[sCell.RowIndex].Tag != null)
           {
               var comboItems = DGV.Rows[sCell.RowIndex].Tag as string[];
               DGV.Columns[sCell.ColumnIndex].CellTemplate = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
               var newCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell { Value = sCell.Value };
               newCell.Items.AddRange(comboItems);
               DGV.Rows[sCell.RowIndex].Cells[sCell.ColumnIndex] = newCell;
               lastDGVCellInEdit= DGV.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex];
           }
       }
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35145596)